# Can I crawl locally hosted website using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I created a website using HTML and CSS and now, I need to crawl through it to download the images. If the link for locally hosted website is like: 
  http://localhost/Webpage.html Is it possible?

Comment: If *you* have created the site, why do you need to crawl it or download anything from it?!

Comment: That is a part of my project. I need to crawl it to upload the same image in next website

Answer (score 1):

Yes, why not ? As long as your program is running on a machine which has access to this address.

Comment: Can I crawl using beautiful soup? I tried it that way but, it shows url error. How can I do it?

Comment: I cannot help without seeing the code, please edit your question with your code and the exact error it throws